# Saber que Procedure ou sessão está deixando cursores abertos

Tags: oracle

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de descobrir que sessão ou procedure(s) estão deixando cursores abertos no Oracle, algumas vezes (nem sempre) ocorre o erro:

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa página  da documentação do Oracle 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/admin.1112/e27149/cursor.htm#OMADM5352). Ela possui queries para verificar as sessões e SQL dos cursores abertos.

Answer (score -1):

Como o Anthony mencionou, você pode fazer uma consulta para identificar (logado como system):

```
-- recuperar sessao para matar lock
select
   sid
   ||','||
   serial# sessao
from
   v$session
where
   sid in ( 
      SELECT a.SESSION_ID      
      FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT A, ALL_OBJECTS B      
      WHERE A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID   
    );
```

Se quiser "matar" o que esta bloqueado:

```
-- matar lock   
alter system kill session '99,16886';  --sessao
```